# json response from httpwebresponse

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am getting pure json response in httpwebresponse but not able to get it in out in htmldoc or other...

here is the code..

```
public HtmlDocument Load(string url, string method)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        HtmlDocument doc;
        if ((uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps) ||
            (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp))
        {
            doc = LoadUrl(uri, method, null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            if (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeFile)
            {
                doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = false;
                doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
                if (OverrideEncoding != null)
                    doc.Load(url, OverrideEncoding);
                else
                    doc.DetectEncodingAndLoad(url, _autoDetectEncoding);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new HtmlWebException("Unsupported uri scheme: '" + uri.Scheme + "'.");
            }
        }
        if (PreHandleDocument != null)
        {
            PreHandleDocument(doc);
        }
        return doc;
    }
```

Can Anyone please tell me how to get same json text on doc from httpwebresponse..

Comment: Json is not Html. If the response is json, then why do you use HtmlAgilityPack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply I used below code and resolved my issue...

```
 using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
 {
       var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
       doc.LoadHtml(result.ToString());
 }
```